# Any reason why prior term changes are picking territory code from address that was updated in future terms?

Tags: guidewire

Currently system is using AddressToPolicyAddressSyncedField to get territory field value. We have a policy where Term-1 have address-1 and Term-2 have address-2. But when we are trying to perform prior term change, it is getting territory value from future term.

Need some insights on how this AddressToPolicyAddressSyncedField works?

Appreciate if someone can point me to any existing GW articles or discussion around this issue.

We tried recreating issue but it is not reproducible. But it is happening on few policies.

Answer (score 8):

This is the OOTB behaviour. All Policy fields are revisioned and remain locked once the branch is promoted (bound). Account however is not a revisioned graph, there is only one version of the Account record/graph in the database at any given time.

PolicyCenter synchronises selected (syncable) fields to/from the Account once you have an open (unbound) transaction, in your case the Account Address.

When the Policy Address was updated during Term-2 transaction, it got synced with the Account (so the account address was overridden with address-2 data). The moment you create a new transaction, **regardless of its effective date**, the Policy graph is synced with the information from the Account, hence it may appear you get future dated changes, but in reality a copy of the current Account address was synced.

You can find this mechanism documented here https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/pc/202310/app/app/pc/topics/c_db4799826.html (requires login).

Comment: To expand on this solution, the way to prevent this is to never "EDIT" entities that do this syncing (so PolicyLocation, Contact, PolicyAddress).  ALWAYS create a new instance of these objects and shift relationships to the new entity as needed.  I know this sounds disruptive but it will prevent so many issues that I always recommend this as best practice behavior.  To help implement this I strongly recommend restricting edit permissions on these entities to few if any people.  You can modify this simplistic approach - for example allow edits for x days after the create date.